# How to nest a NSTimer within another one?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I would like to have an NSTimer which executes every 1 second and have another NSTimer which executes within that timer slightly less than 1 second.

Actually I am not sure what is the best way to do this, but I would like a random image to appear every second and then disappear after after that second.

So I need some kind of stall or something which can pass the time and then execute the hide button again.

If I set the buttons hidden to TRUE and then set it to FALSE, this appearance time will be so short, how can I stall or make the second pass and then hide the image again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting yourself into a constant cycle of showing and hiding the object after a specified interval until you interrupt it by using the [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) method reciprocally in two counter-acting methods:

```
//On initialization, make a first call to the hide method
//to be executed after a delay
-(void) viewDidload {
    [myObject setHidden:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideObject) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

//Whenever the hide gets called, hide, then make a call to the show method
//to be executed after a delay
-(void) hideObject {
    [myObject setHidden:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showObject) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

//Whenever the show gets called, show, then make a call to the hide method
//to be executed after a delay
-(void) showObject {
    [myObject setHidden:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showObject) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

You can interrupt the cycle by putting an `if` statement which checks some end condition for you around the [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) call .

Comment: Hi Chris. Is there another way to do something after a delay? rather than myObject setHidden , because myObject changes every second the timer ticks. When I set myObject to the appropriate button, the buttons dont work properly in terms of hiding and showing. I would just like to execute a statement after around 1 second.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is @Peter Zich's answer what you are looking for?

Comment: No it isnt what I am trying to do. I basically want nothing to execute on that method for 1 sec and then run my hidden = YES code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using NSTimer's `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`. This will let you have the timer fire at a regular interval (if you set `repeats` to `YES`) and you can specify a `fireDate` (the first time the timer is fired) to immediately for one loop and slightly later for the other. What's better about this method compared to `performSelector` is that it can be easily terminated by sending `invalidate` to the timers and will not be delayed by any blocking code you might have in either of your methods.